# Pulling image out of html from database

Tags: php, html

I have an addon in xenforo that I'm editing, and it pulls in an RSS feed, saves feed data to a database, and then serves the data into a template.

My issue is that it currently serves the description into the template with the image ommitted so that it can show more text from the description. This is where the work is being done:

```
// foreach condition
    foreach ($results as $k => $v)
    {
        
        // for each multidimensional array
        foreach ($v as $k2 => $v2)
        {
            // get description
            if ($k2 == 'description')
            {
                if ($limitDescription >= 0)
                { 
                    $results[$k]['description'] = html_entity_decode($results[$k]['description']);

                    $results[$k]['description'] = strip_tags($results[$k]['description']);
                    
                    if (!$multibyte AND $limitDescription > 0)
                    {
                        $results[$k]['description'] = substr($results[$k]['description'], 0, $limitDescription) . ' ...';
                    }
                    
                    if ($multibyte AND $limitDescription > 0)
                    {
                        $results[$k]['description'] = mb_substr($results[$k]['description'], 0, $limitDescription) . ' ...';
                    }
                    
                    if ($limitDescription == 0)
                    {
                        $results[$k]['description'] = '';
                    }
                }
            }
       }
 }
```

How can I alter this to actually grab the image and only a bit of the text from the description? Ideally I would create a new variable here (one called image, one called description) but it all comes from the description field in the database. I'm just lost as to how to actually grab the  tag here. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: you will need to show the schema of your database table.  Try doing a print_r on $results and show us what you get

Comment: If I do the print_r it seems to get encoded on the front-end but I see the image on the page and the img tag in the inspector. The schema is just ID->int, Description->var_char(5000)

Comment: you can also issue an exit() after the print_r to terminate the php script.  Unless the description is actually embedded in the image it's a separate item in the database.  You need to find where the image is stored.  you could try select * from the database and then do a print_r on that result

Comment: It's not, it's stored in the database as html like ```<div><p>This is a desciprion test</p><img src="#"></div>```

Comment: what's the src?  # will just keep you on the same page.

Comment: @DCR That was just an example, the actual HTML for one of the elements (when dumping $v2) is: ``` <div><p>Test out the business integration tools today</p><img src="https://play-lh.googleusercontent.com/EUQGH40jV55Dm2mcGzT9I2_vSfl_rJv88dfrR3JGJkxgQMe2j4bXoFd-tvuYLSGhFIQ=s180-rw"></div>```

Comment: Also, I updated source code because I left out the main foreach loops before getting the description. Sorry about that

Comment: it looks like the image is not stored in the database.  Rather, you have a link to that image.  Parse the link and create an image tag with it.

Comment: i should have phrased better originally, I was aware it was just the link in the html within the database, but my question is moreso how to do that ere (find the img tag and parse the link

Comment: I've tried using ```preg_match_all('/<img.*?src=[\'"](.*?)[\'"].*?>/i', $v2, $matches);
        
                        $results[$k]['image'] = $matches[1];``` But it's printing an array when I use it on the frontend

Comment: Is this what you have now - <div><p>Test out the business integration tools today</p><img src="play-lh.googleusercontent.com/…>   --- and you want to parse the the link address?